# All Table Name List

Tags: sql, database, oracle, error-handling

How do I check List of All Table Name In My Oracle SQL Developer?
Like
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ALL_TABLES`, `USER_TABLES`, or `DBA_TABLES`.

```
select * from ALL_TABLES;
```

- `ALL_TABLES` -- All tables accessible to your schema.
- `USER_TABLES` -- All the tables owned by your schema
- `DBA_TABLES` -- All the tables in the database from all the schema. This view will be available for you if you have enough rights to select from `DBA_` views

And If you are talking about SQL Developer then you will definitely find it under the table menu from the left pane under MURAD --> Table. But you are not able to see any tables as I think your schema do not have any tables.

If you think that the MURAD has tables but not listed here then try to right-click on the `tables menu` and click on `Clear filter`